What's the right sound of 浣
What is the pronounce of 浣? In the 教育部國語小字典, it sounds wan with 3rd tone, and it doesn't list any other sounds, but in dictionary published in China, this word has huan sound with 4th tone. Neither list the other sounds, so is this the heteronym phenomenon or just different pronunciation in different places?

教育部國語小字典 seems to differ from the 教育部重編國語辭典, despite both being from the Ministry of Education in Taiwan. The former lists wǎn as standard, while the latter lists huǎn as standard (and wǎn as a variant reading). However, I'm under the impression that wǎn is the more common reading in Taiwan. In Mainland China, the standard reading is huàn.

Oh I see, thanks!

汉典 - 浣 [huàn], [huǎn 又音 wǎn - 國語辭典].
浣 《康熙字典》:
【唐韻】【集韻】胡玩切，音換[huàn]。濯衣垢也。一曰滌也。【史記·萬石君傳】身自浣滌。

又【廣韻】【正韻】胡管切【集韻】戸管切，音緩[huǎn]。

又古緩切，音管[guǎn]。義同。

又戸版切，音睆[huǎn]。水名，在江夏。【水經注】辱水，出于鳥山，俗謂之秀延水，東流得浣水口。

又江口。【廣輿記】雲南臨安府寧州有浣江。　本作亦作澣[huàn]。


浣 音韵方言 - 唐代读音 huɑ̌n

Both 浣huàn and 浣wǎn mean “wash”, so they’re just different in pronunciation.
PS: Your second link doesn’t point to a dictionary.
